# How does one dynamically set a color of a country through a var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

Anyone used http://github.com/manifestinteractive/jqvmap/ ?

These work:

```
$('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', { us: '#8EE5EE' });
$('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', { 'us': '#8EE5EE' });
```

But, this doesnt:

```
country_name = 'us';
$('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', { country_name: '#8EE5EE' });
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's not how object literals work. The key part in the key-value pair is interpreted as a literal string. You need to use bracket-syntax to have a dynamic key name. It's that or `eval`, and you don't want to use `eval`.

```js
var country_colors = {};
var country_name = 'us';

country_colors[country_name] = '#8EE5EE';

$('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', country_colors);
```

Comment: Michael - this is the closest I've been all day, so thanks!  Wondering if you could show an example given a comma separated list of states that will all be set to the same color?  The list is dynamic and stored in a js variable currently.  An example in the variable might be (tx,co,in,id)